# Error.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase

Tags: java, android, exception

Hi I have a class that inside information by barcode reader is stored in a database.

I can't enter my activity and the program stops.

What i should do?Thanks.

I have this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.mahdishekari.mycollectbill, PID: 23050
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mahdishekari.mycollectbill/ghabz.mahdishekari.app.Scann}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2440)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:163)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5585)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
                  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:269)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                  at ghabz.mahdishekari.app.C0238u.m1320a(C0238u.java:30)
                  at ghabz.mahdishekari.app.Scann.onCreate(Scann.java:81)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6279)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:163) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5585) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

My Activity(Scann):

```
public class Scann extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
static ArrayList f986a;
Button f987b;
ListView f988c;
SharedPreferences f989d;
private am f990e;

public void onActivityResult(int i, int i2, Intent intent) {
    C0231n a = C0228k.m1310a(i, i2, intent);
    if (a != null && a.m1319a() != null) {
        String a2 = a.m1319a();
        String substring = a2.substring(0, 13);
        a2 = a2.substring(13);
        while (a2.charAt(0) == '0') {
            a2 = a2.substring(1);
        }
        while (substring.charAt(0) == '0') {
            substring = substring.substring(1);
        }
        a2 = an.m1287f(a2);
        substring = an.m1287f(substring);
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SuccessfulScanActivity.class);
        intent2.putExtra("sg", substring);
        intent2.putExtra("sp", a2);
        intent2.putExtra("new", true);
        startActivity(intent2);
        finish();
    }
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_scan:
            if (GhabzakApplication.f980b) {
                Builder builder = new Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.free_title));
                builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.free_desc));
                builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.free_yes), new C0233p(this));
                builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.free_no, new Object[]{"10"}), new C0234q(this));
                AlertDialog create = builder.create();
                create.show();
                create.getButton(-2).setEnabled(false);
                new C0235r(this, 10000, 1000, create).start();
            } else if (this.f989d.getBoolean("scanner", false)) {
                new C0228k(this).m1316a();
            } else {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, ScanActivity.class));
            }
        default:
    }
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    this.f990e = ((GhabzakApplication) GhabzakApplication.m1264a()).m1265b();
    setContentView((int) R.layout.activity_main2);
    this.f987b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_scan);
    this.f987b.setOnClickListener(this);
    this.f988c = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_history);
    this.f988c.setAdapter(new C0226i(C0238u.m1320a()));
    C0240w.m1331a((Context) this);
    C0240w.m1334b(this);
    this.f989d = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.manual:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ManualActivity.class));
            break;
        case R.id.menu_invite:
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.SUBJECT", getResources().getString(R.string.share_subject));
            intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", getResources().getString(R.string.share_body));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getResources().getString(R.string.share_chooser)));
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    this.f988c = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_history);
    f986a = C0238u.m1320a();
    this.f988c.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.list_empty_view));
    this.f988c.setAdapter(new C0226i(f986a));
    this.f988c.setOnItemClickListener(new C0232o(this));
}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    this.f990e.m1276a(this);
}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    this.f990e.m1278b(this);
}
```

My database:

```
public class C0238u extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public C0238u(Context context) {
    super(context, "scans.db", null, 1);
}

public static ArrayList m1320a() {
    SQLiteDatabase writableDatabase = new C0238u(GhabzakApplication.m1264a()).getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor rawQuery = writableDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM scans ORDER BY _id DESC", null);
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
    if (rawQuery.moveToFirst()) {
        while (!rawQuery.isAfterLast()) {
            Long valueOf = Long.valueOf(rawQuery.getLong(rawQuery.getColumnIndex("date")));
            String a = an.m1280a(valueOf.longValue());
            String string = rawQuery.getString(rawQuery.getColumnIndex("sg"));
            String string2 = rawQuery.getString(rawQuery.getColumnIndex("sp"));
            arrayList.add(new C0227j(a, valueOf, an.m1284c(string2), rawQuery.getString(rawQuery.getColumnIndex("trace")), string, string2));
            rawQuery.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    rawQuery.close();
    writableDatabase.close();
    return arrayList;
}

public static void m1321a(long j, String str, String str2, String str3) {
    SQLiteDatabase writableDatabase = new C0238u(GhabzakApplication.m1264a()).getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("date", Long.valueOf(j));
    contentValues.put("sg", str);
    contentValues.put("sp", str2);
    if (str3 != null) {
        contentValues.put("trace", str3);
    }
    writableDatabase.insert("scans", null, contentValues);
    writableDatabase.close();
}

public static boolean m1322a(String str, String str2) {
    SQLiteDatabase writableDatabase = new C0238u(GhabzakApplication.m1264a()).getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor query = writableDatabase.query("scans", new String[]{"_id", "sg"}, "sg=?", new String[]{str}, null, null, null, null);
    if (query == null) {
        writableDatabase.close();
        return false;
    } else if (query.getCount() > 0) {
        query = writableDatabase.query("scans", new String[]{"_id", "sp"}, "sp=?", new String[]{str2}, null, null, null, null);
        if (query == null || query.getCount() <= 0) {
            query.close();
            writableDatabase.close();
            return false;
        }
        query.close();
        writableDatabase.close();
        return true;
    } else {
        query.close();
        writableDatabase.close();
        return false;
    }
}

public static boolean m1323a(String str, String str2, String str3) {
    String f = an.m1287f(str);
    String f2 = an.m1287f(str2);
    String f3 = an.m1287f(str3);
    SQLiteDatabase writableDatabase = new C0238u(GhabzakApplication.m1264a()).getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor rawQuery = writableDatabase.rawQuery("UPDATE scans SET trace = " + f3 + " WHERE " + "sp" + " = " + f2 + " AND " + "sg" + " = " + f, null);
    if (rawQuery.getCount() > 0) {
        rawQuery.close();
        writableDatabase.close();
        return true;
    }
    rawQuery.close();
    writableDatabase.close();
    return false;
}

public static String m1324b(String str, String str2) {
    SQLiteDatabase writableDatabase = new C0238u(GhabzakApplication.m1264a()).getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor rawQuery = writableDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM scans WHERE sp = " + str2 + " AND " + "sg" + " = " + str, null);
    if (rawQuery.getCount() > 0) {
        rawQuery.moveToFirst();
        String string = rawQuery.getString(rawQuery.getColumnIndex("trace"));
        rawQuery.close();
        writableDatabase.close();
        return string;
    }
    rawQuery.close();
    writableDatabase.close();
    return null;
}

public static void m1325b() {
    try {
        File externalStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dataDirectory = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        if (externalStorageDirectory.canWrite()) {
            File file = new File(dataDirectory, "/data/" + GhabzakApplication.m1264a().getPackageName() + "/databases/" + "scans.db");
            Object channel = new FileInputStream(new File(externalStorageDirectory, "ghabzak.gbf")).getChannel();
            FileChannel channel2 = new FileOutputStream(file).getChannel();
            channel2.transferFrom((ReadableByteChannel) channel, 0, channel2.size());
            channel2.close();
            channel2.close();
            Toast.makeText(GhabzakApplication.m1264a().getApplicationContext(), GhabzakApplication.m1264a().getString(R.string.backup_success),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(GhabzakApplication.m1264a().getApplicationContext(), GhabzakApplication.m1264a().getString(R.string.backup_fail), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public static void m1326c() {
    try {
        File externalStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dataDirectory = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        if (externalStorageDirectory.canWrite()) {
            File file = new File(dataDirectory, "/data/" + GhabzakApplication.m1264a().getPackageName() + "/databases/" + "temp.db");
            Object channel = new FileInputStream(new File(externalStorageDirectory, "ghabzak.gbf")).getChannel();
            FileChannel channel2 = new FileOutputStream(file).getChannel();
            channel2.transferFrom((ReadableByteChannel) channel, 0, channel2.size());
            channel2.close();
            channel2.close();
            C0239v c0239v = new C0239v(GhabzakApplication.m1264a());
            Iterator it = C0239v.m1329a().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                C0227j c0227j = (C0227j) it.next();
                if (!C0238u.m1322a(c0227j.m1300b(), c0227j.m1301c())) {
                    C0238u.m1321a(c0227j.m1306h().longValue(), c0227j.m1300b(), c0227j.m1301c(), c0227j.m1304f());
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(GhabzakApplication.m1264a().getApplicationContext(), GhabzakApplication.m1264a().getString(R.string.backup_success),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(GhabzakApplication.m1264a().getApplicationContext(), GhabzakApplication.m1264a().getString(R.string.backup_fail),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public static boolean m1327c(String str, String str2) {
    String f = an.m1287f(str);
    String f2 = an.m1287f(str2);
    SQLiteDatabase writableDatabase = new C0238u(GhabzakApplication.m1264a()).getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor rawQuery = writableDatabase.rawQuery("DELETE FROM scans WHERE sp = " + f2 + " AND " + "sg" + " = " + f, null);
    if (rawQuery.getCount() > 0) {
        rawQuery.close();
        writableDatabase.close();
        return true;
    }
    rawQuery.close();
    writableDatabase.close();
    return false;
}

public static void m1328d() {
    File externalStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dataDirectory = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    try {
        if (externalStorageDirectory.canWrite()) {
            File file = new File(dataDirectory, "/data/" + GhabzakApplication.m1264a().getPackageName() + "/databases/" + "scans.db");
            File file2 = new File(externalStorageDirectory, "ghabzak.gbf");
            Object channel = new FileInputStream(file).getChannel();
            FileChannel channel2 = new FileOutputStream(file2).getChannel();
            channel2.transferFrom((ReadableByteChannel) channel, 0, channel2.size());
            channel2.close();
            channel2.close();
            Toast.makeText(GhabzakApplication.m1264a().getApplicationContext(), GhabzakApplication.m1264a().getString(R.string.backup_success),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(GhabzakApplication.m1264a().getApplicationContext(), GhabzakApplication.m1264a().getString(R.string.backup_fail),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sQLiteDatabase) {
    sQLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table scans(_id integer primary key autoincrement, date integer not null,sg text not null,sp text not null,trace text);");
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sQLiteDatabase, int i, int i2) {
    if (GhabzakApplication.f979a) {
        Log.w(C0238u.class.getName(), "Upgrading database from version " + i + " to " + i2 + ", which will destroy all old data");
    }
    sQLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS scans");
    onCreate(sQLiteDatabase);
}
```

Comment: your data base is not storing data and retrieving you in null  databse

Comment: first check you have currectly stored data or not